# Why are there two NSNotFound?

Tags: swift, xcode, constants

If I activate autocomplete with <kbd>⎋</kbd> there are two `NSNotFound` with a green `V`-symbol (I do not know *what does the M / V / C / # actually stand for*).

If I open the documentation there is only one definition of `NSNotFound` as Int.

It is the same from *Xcode 6* to *Xcode 8*.

Is it a bug, that there are two `NSNotFound`s or where is the second defined?

Just open a Playground and put in this line:

```
import Foundation

NSNotF // use autocomplete here.
```

Comment: Check out subsequent self-answered question <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731622/swift-ambiguos-reference-to-nsnotfound">here</a>

Comment: @Grimxn You didn't even read my question.

Answer (score 1):

You used auto complete with escape, it can be any keyboard shortcut (escape is just the default one).

The little symbols indicate what it is:
`V` is a variable you defined in your scope.
`C` is a class.
`S` is a struct.
`T` is a typealias.

As why there are two `NSNotFound` in the autocompoletion, I do not know.