# Swift: ambiguous reference to NSNotFound

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, swift

After adding a bridging header to some Objective-C code I started receiving a compiler error about `NSNotFound` being an ambiguous reference.  My guess is that it can be fixed with  some sort of module prefix...

Comment: I hate those guys who downvote other's question without any reason. I uproot for you!

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Change it to: `Foundation.NSNotFound`

Comment: Great within a minute you have answered your question yourself.

Comment: And there was a recent open question on the topic... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681734/why-are-there-two-nsnotfound-error-ambigious-nsnotfound

Comment: There's wasn't one in my initial search and SO provides an "Answer your own question feature" so I thought I'd add it to save someone else 2 minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore in Xcode beta 4. You can just use *NSNotFound*

Comment: @bagusflyer - Using Xcode 6 beta 4 and I still needed Foundation.NSNotFound